# How do I automate the padding for arbitary images using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is a further question based on this answer:

[How can I implement a fisheye lens effect (barrel transformation) in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589851/how-can-i-implement-this-visual-effect-in-matlab/2589957#2589957)

The general solution should work for all background colors and length/width ratios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is often the case, there are a number of different ways to do this in MATLAB. I'll list a few examples for padding [RGB images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-20224)...

### Solution #1: Add padding with [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html) to make a square image

This solution takes a given color `padColor` and replicates it using the function [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) to create padding of the right size, shape, and color. The padding is then added to the sides of the image using the function [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html):

```
[r,c,d] = size(rgbImage);  %# Get the image dimensions
nPad = abs(c-r)/2;         %# The padding size
padColor = [1 1 1];        %# RGB triple for pad color (white)
padColor = reshape(padColor,1,1,3);  %# Reshape pad color to 1-by-1-by-3
if c > r                   %# Pad rows
  newImage = cat(1,repmat(padColor,floor(nPad),c),...  %# Top padding
                   rgbImage,...                        %# Image
                   repmat(padColor,ceil(nPad),c));     %# Bottom padding
elseif r > c               %# Pad columns
  newImage = cat(2,repmat(padColor,r,floor(nPad)),...  %# Left padding
                   rgbImage,...                        %# Image
                   repmat(padColor,r,ceil(nPad)));     %# Right padding
end
```

You can modify the above solution to work for [indexed](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-17587), [grayscale](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-13941), or [binary images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-33397) by replacing the two lines defining the `padColor` with one of the following:

```
padColor = uint8(1);    %# For an indexed image (index of color to use)
padColor = uint8(255);  %# For a grayscale image (white)
padColor = true;        %# For a binary image (white)
```

### Solution #2: Make a blank square image and insert the original image

This solution takes a given color `padColor` and replicates it using the function [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) to create a blank square image of that color. The original image is then inserted into this blank image in a centered position:

```
[r,c,d] = size(rgbImage);  %# Get the image dimensions
padColor = [1 1 1];        %# RGB triple for pad color (white)
padColor = reshape(padColor,1,1,3);  %# Reshape pad color to 1-by-1-by-3
if c > r                   %# Pad rows
  newImage = repmat(padColor,c);  %# Make c-by-c-by-3 matrix of given color
  rowIndex = floor((c-r)/2);      %# Row index for inserting image
  newImage(rowIndex+(1:r),:,:) = rgbImage;     %# Insert the image
elseif r > c               %# Pad columns
  newImage = repmat(padColor,r);  %# Make r-by-r-by-3 matrix of given color
  columnIndex = floor((r-c)/2);   %# Column index for inserting image
  newImage(:,columnIndex+(1:c),:) = rgbImage;  %# Insert the image
end
```

You can modify the above solution to work for [indexed](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-17587), [grayscale](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-13941), or [binary images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-33397) by replacing the two lines defining the `padColor` with one of the following:

```
padColor = uint8(1);    %# For an indexed image (index of color to use)
padColor = uint8(255);  %# For a grayscale image (white)
padColor = true;        %# For a binary image (white)
```

### Solution #3: Use [PADARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/padarray.html)

This solution uses the function [PADARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/padarray.html) to create the padding to make the image square. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to specify the padding color you want for [RGB images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-20224) when using this solution (see below). However, you can use the `'replicate'` argument to have [PADARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/padarray.html) simply replicate the color at the edges of the image where it is adding the padding:

```
[r,c,d] = size(rgbImage);  %# Get the image dimensions
nPad = abs(c-r)/2;         %# The padding size
if c > r                   %# Pad rows
  newImage = padarray(rgbImage,[floor(nPad) 0],...  %# Pad top
                      'replicate','pre');
  newImage = padarray(newImage,[ceil(nPad) 0],...   %# Pad bottom
                      'replicate','post');
elseif r > c               %# Pad columns
  newImage = padarray(rgbImage,[0 floor(nPad)],...  %# Pad left
                      'replicate','pre');
  newImage = padarray(newImage,[0 ceil(nPad)],...   %# Pad right
                      'replicate','post');
end
```

This solution will work for [indexed](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-17587), [grayscale](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-13941), or [binary images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-33397). For these three image types, you have the option to replace the `'replicate'` argument with a scalar value that you want to use for the padding (i.e. `uint8(255)` for white padding in a grayscale image). For [RGB images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html#f14-20224), replacing the `'replicate'` argument with a single value will only allow you to create padding colors that are gray shades ranging from white to black (i.e. `1` creates white padding).

Comment: @user198729: The function RESHAPE changes the size of a matrix or vector. I change `padColor` from a 1-by-3 matrix into a 1-by-1-by-3 matrix because that makes it easier to later expand it to an N-by-M-by-3 padding matrix using REPMAT.

Comment: Seems there is no logic to retrieve the background color for padding,so I assume it's hardcoded and this won't work for all background colors?

Comment: @user198729: I added a few more options for you to choose from. You can easily add logic yourself to choose what you deem the "background color" to be. For example, you could choose the top left corner color of the image to be the background color by saying `padColor = rgbImage(1,1,:);`. Alternatively, the third solution I list above will simply replicate the edge colors of the image to color the padded areas.

Comment: Thanks in advance,seems quite a lot for me to digest,I'll accept this as soon as I understand it:)

Comment: What does `...` mean in `cat(2,repmat(padColor,r,floor(nPad)),...` ?

Comment: @user198729: The `...` is the line continuation operator (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-5789.html#f0-5857), which allows you to write a multiple-line statement in cases where just one line would be very long. It generally improves the format and readability of the code by avoiding the need to scroll left and right to read everything.

Comment: @gnovice, sorry to peppering about this question,I tried to assign `padColor` another value:`padColor=1.2;padColor = reshape(meanColor,1,1,3);` but got a error:`To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.`,how to do it the proper way?

Comment: @user198729: You have to replace *both* lines with your new line defining `padColor` as a scalar value. So, just get rid of the line that does the reshaping since it isn't necessary when `padColor` isn't an RGB triple.