# How can I transform a fish_eye image to a flat rectangular image?

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to do a "inverse" fisheye lens effect, which means to transform a "fisheye" image to rectangular/square image using matlab for few weeks,
but still without a good solution.

Basically it is just an inverse of [How can I implement a fisheye lens effect (barrel transformation) in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589851/how-can-i-implement-this-visual-effect-in-matlab)

Could anyone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477774/correcting-fisheye-distortion-programmatically/2487365#2487365

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Jean-Yves Bouguet's [Camera Calibration Toolkit](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/).  If you have the camera you can follow his steps to calibrate the camera yourself.  Otherwise you will have to know something about the geometry of the lens.