# How to bulge an image using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have an input cylinder image. That image I have to scale in a particular way. That is I have to scale the image in the middle part only. 
My input image is [image]

I want output image as

[image]

I am trying to achieve this using Opencv and C++. What kind of transformation do I have to use to achieve this result.

Comment: do you want to preserve the straight vertical bright highlight on the cylinder (as in your example) or is it ok to transform it, too (so it would be bulged, too)?

Comment: @Micka No need to preserve that. That can be bulged too... Since I created the output image using photoshop, it came like that... Thats all...

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589851/how-can-i-implement-a-fisheye-lens-effect-barrel-transformation-in-matlab ?

Comment: @akamath Not fish eye effect